# Htaccess from root folder affecting subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am having terrible trouble I can not figure out. I've honestly spent hours trying to find a solution but I have no idea what is going on.

I have a domain, domain.tld, that has various files in the public_html folder on my server.
I have a subdomain, clients.domain.tld, that also has various files in public_html/clients/ subfolder.

My goal is to have those two directories completely separate from each other. I do not want people to be able to access /clients/ subfolder through domain.tld

For some reason, the htaccess file in the clients subfolder seems to be inheriting the properties from the root htaccess file.

It is important to note, both "sites" are set up to process all requests through index.php of their respective base folders.

My Issues:

1. I can access files from the clients subfolder through the domain.tld, for instance, domain.tld/clients/assets/js/app.js will return the file.
2. I can not, for the life of me, get the root htaccess to redirect all requests for domain.tld/clients/ to clients.domain.tld
3. I need to let users access files in subfolders, except for certain subfolders, for example, I have a subfolder "source" within both public_html/source/ and public_html/clients/source/ which contains php files for the app. I do not want people to be able to directly access those, all requests need to go through index.php that parses url requests.
4. domain.tld needs to redirect all www.domain.tld requests to non-www.
5. clients.domain.tld needs to always use https.
6. www.clients.domain.tld needs to redirect to non-www!

domain.tld htaccess file (located in public_html/.htaccess):

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ptr.cnsat.com.cn spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Via pinappleproxy spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spammer=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer poker spammer=yes

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spammer 
Deny from ptr.cnsat.com.cn

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Baiduspider|HTTrack|Yandex).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# RedirectMatch ^/clients/(.*)$ https://clients.domain.tld/$1
# I tried this but it redirects requests in the form of
# "https://clients.domain.tld/clients/add" to
# "https://clients.domain.tld/add" which is no good!

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# from what I understand, !-d and !-f means exclude directories
# and exclude files, is there a way to say exclude /source/ for example?
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

clients.domain.tld htaccess file (located in public_html/clients/.htaccess):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Baiduspider|HTTrack|Yandex).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

I highly appreciate anyone that can help me figure these things out, I know I'm asking for a lot of things at once, but I've tried so much I am completely stuck.
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Have you looked into using Virtual Hosts instead, this will allow you to completely separate the two sets of files.

Comment: @NigelRen I haven't, I am using cPanel so I haven't really looked into that as an option. Can you recommend any guides to start informing myself on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: There seems a good example using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts